# why I cannot open the excel file which create by fastExcel

Tags: java, excel

as the title said;
I create a .xls file by the lib called fastExcel successfully,but I cannot open it on my win7 systems normally.
this is my code for create the .xls file:

```
    private static  List<String[]> readLocationInfos(String path, String type) throws Exception {
        Workbook workBook = FastExcel.createReadableWorkbook(new File(path));
        workBook.open();
        Sheet s = workBook.getSheet(0); 
        List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 
        for (int i = s.getFirstRow(); i < s.getLastRow(); i++) { 
            String[] row = s.getRow(i);
            result.add(row);
        } 
        //          if(i!=0)
        //              converte(row, type);
        workBook.close();
        return result;
    }



    private static void output(List<String[]> list, String outputPath) throws ExcelException, IOException {
        File outputFile = new File(outputPath);
        Workbook workBook = FastExcel.createWriteableWorkbook(outputFile);
        workBook.open();
        Sheet sheet = workBook.addStreamSheet("sheet1");
        for(String[] row : list)
            sheet.addRow(row);
        workBook.close();   
   }
```

I read the datas from another .xls file,and i want to do some converte to generate a new .xls file;
At last,I can read the new .xls file by the readLocationInfos method,but only can't open on my win7 system?
Will it was cause by a license problem?
Can anyone help me? thanks a lot..

Comment: Do you mean that you can't open it with Excel ? If yes, what happens when you try ? Get an error ? Which one ?

Comment: i use microsoft office 2013 Excel to open it..and   it said that the content may has some problem ,would you like to try to restore it?if yes than choose ‘Y'..no matter which I choosed,than there was nothing to show.

Comment: I had sent the new file to my friends who use differernt version of Excel..to try to open it ..but it was fail too.  :(

Comment: I'd be surprised if it had anything to do with a license problem. The Excel file you are creating has invalid format. I suggest you to check the doc of that library you are using and try to find out what is your mistake. This is not a Java problem. If you want to seek advice you need someone with knowledge of that library.

Comment: Maybe also seeing how others do that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fastExcel

Comment: when I change another lib （POI）,It works.anyway,thanks for your advice.

Comment: You are welcome. That probably means that the way your code was using the first library had a problem and the code you wrote to use POI doesn't.